# SettingsActivity template

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have simple question. I created activity form template (SettingsActivity) - using eclipse and ADT and this template works fine but when I run this template app on tablet, setting are shown in list no in two columns. I thought that when we use header's two-pane view on tablet is crated automatically. What I must add to display settings in two-pane mode on tablet?

Comment: give some code so that one can help

Comment: Do you use Fragments? Show your code.

Comment: Sorry, I added code now :)

Comment: What API are you running this on and what is the the tablet's screen size?

Comment: API 18. I tested it on Genymotion emulator as nexus 7 (1280x800).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create a Preference activity using the wizard I also get the following code, you sure you don't have it as well?

These determine when to show that two pane view.

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
}

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Determines whether the simplified settings UI should be shown. This is
 * true if this is forced via {@link #ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS}, or the device
 * doesn't have newer APIs like {@link PreferenceFragment}, or the device
 * doesn't have an extra-large screen. In these cases, a single-pane
 * "simplified" settings UI should be shown.
 */
private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
    return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB || !isXLargeTablet(context);
}
```